# ngRoute don't display view with in ngView

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

I'm starting with a basic app with c# web api + AngularJS. I'm using AngularJS ngRoute for routing. The page is perfectly loaded, and the code in the secondary files is displayed correctly. The problem is with the file (or code) templated with ngRoute... here is my code...

my app.js:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
App.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

my Index.html:

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" ng-app>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="main-header" ng-include src="'views/common/header.html'"></header>
        <!-- Menú Principal -->
        <aside class="main-sidebar" ng-include src="'views/common/sidebar.html'"></aside>

        <!-- Contenido de la página -->
        <div class="content-wrapper" ng-view>

        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="main-footer" ng-include src="'views/common/footer.html'"></footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: what version of angularjs are you using?  I wouldn't expect any of this code to work unless you are using an absolutely ancient version.... blank `ng-app` declarations haven't been supported in a very long time (1.2x).  Try `ng-app="App"`.

Comment: also, are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Im using AngularJS v1.7.2. When I change ng-app to ng-app="App" Angular stop working and I see some error in the console log.

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/modulerr?p0

Comment: Full error in the question body please!  I doubt that "angular stops working";  I suspect that angular was never doing anything in the first place, unless you have more than one `ng-app` somewhere in your code that you aren't showing here....

Answer (score 0):

i wasn't passing the dependency injection for $routeProvider. I change it and then i change ng-app for ng-app="App" and start working fine. Thanks all!